# Can i config the server apache config file because in my site is redirecting to indedx.html instead of index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

http://naijashop.com.ng/index.html

I have added the htaccess mode rewrite code but still it seems not working 
Hope get solution for this error soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please specify what all settings you have made, or please refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945047/htaccess-not-working-mod-rewrite)

Thanks